# Child list for field “ ” cannot be created, when table name contains "."

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, infragistics, ultrawingrid

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

ds = GetData();//This method reads the .xls file and returns datatable in a dataset.
```

While binding this to UltraGrid.

```
grid.DataSource = ds;
```

Exception caught:  Child list for field “ ” cannot be created.

After few attempts i figure it out if  **DataSet's table name contains "."** then only this exception is thrown.

**Example**:

```
ds.Tables[0].TableName = "AW_MyTable_1.2" //Throws Exception
ds.Tables[0].TableName = "A.W_MyTable_12" //Throws Exception

ds.Tables[0].TableName = "AW_MyTable_12"  //Works Correctly
```

I am unable to understand the reason behind this exception.

Comment: Can you show `GetData`?

Comment: GetData()// This method reads the .xls file and returns datatable in a dataset.  You can use any method I have tested this with 2-3 alternate methods but failed all the time.

Comment: I suppose UltraGrid caches the tables names when you set the DataSource. Are you changing the tables names after data source is set? Try to not do this. Instead, you may create the tables by providing table name as an argument to the table's constructor.

Comment: This article explains what characters are allowed in table names: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/154c19c4-95ba-4b6f-b6ca-479288feabfb/characters-that-are-not-allowed-in-table-name-column-name-in-sql-server-?forum=databasedesign